# In Vue, how to make browser to go back to previous page using window.history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, router

Hi I'm making a webpage based on **Vue**, but I'm in trouble now.
I initially used **router.go(-1)** to prevent access through the address
(ex : ../client/mypage -> ../admin/mypage ) and to redirect to the previous page,
but it didn't work because the page itself was refreshed. (In my opinion,router history stack was empty)

So, what I found is **window.history.go(-1)**, but it didn't work either even though its length was greater than 1.

What's the problem and how should I solve it?

```
    mounted(){
        if (this.auth) { // when you access through address, check the authority  
            this.$router.go(-1); //doesn't work
            window.history.go(-1); //doesn't work either
        }
    }
```

[pic: console.log(window.history)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjvXZ.png)

Comment: Try using `this.$router.back()`

Comment: no it doesn't work..

Comment: and use `return false;` means use any one of the three and `return false` so the url will not navigate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but these are all not working... I just checked beforeRouteEnter and the from value is "/"

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
mounted(){
        if (!this.auth) {  //If not authenticated
            window.history.back();
        }
}
```